# Why is it better to work on a local website copy than live on the website?

Tags: development-environment

I used to work on the live website when I'm editing a website (I'm working alone), but some people told me "it's the old way". I'm inclined to evolve and I like to work, but how can't I lose time doing this?

First, that means that I need to get a copy of the website on my computer. I need to copy the files, dump and restore the database, first waste of time. If my customer adds extension on the website in the meantime(for example, Wordpress) my modification should be impacted then I need to add it on my local copy to. If I need to modify the DB I will need to do it on the local copy too.

Secondly if I want to show a work in progress to my customer I need to apply all modifications to the live website and check than everything works, still a waste of time.

And finally when everything is ok, I need to update again the live website, files and DB.

So, there's two options:

1. this is not the correct way to do and there's tools to do all that transparently (I hope so)
2. this is not a waste of time but a needed time to work properly (I understand why agency have big prices and I'll keep my method)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the complexity of the project and the size of your team.

One of the major risk of working on a live site is the introduction bugs in production. You also want to have some confirmation of functionalities developed from QA or your customer before having your users access them.

Basically, you want to make sure your new code does not break the live site, so working on the local instance could help you in this way, and you could also deploy on the live test site you changes for approval and QA.

Also if you working with a larger team working on the live site just won't scale up and the risk of introducing bug is even higher.

You could consider using docker, to simplify development on your local machine.

Comment: I understand perfectly that in a team it's a big risk but I'm alone.

Comment: @Entretoize you have risks even if you work alone, you can introduce a bug any time in production affecting all your user

Comment: Yes I already that many times, but I don't talk about the fact of having a test environnement, I'm also working on pre-production environnement to prevent that problem, but that's the same problem : adding one more step is a waste of time